# How to animate character on Demand SceneKit Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, animation

hey I'm trying to figure out how to animate a .scn character i can get him in the scene but i can't lets say get him to play his animation when i press a button. Really i just need him to play his animation. back about a month ago i used to import the .scn file then the animation would play automatically as soon as he hit the screen but thats not what i need. I need it to play on demand and not just only when the app launches.

Code:

```
  let GuyScene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/Guy.scn")
    let characterTopLevelNode: SCNNode = GuyScene!.rootNode.childNodeWithName("Guy", recursively: true)!
    node.addChildNode(characterTopLevelNode)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check these two Apple sample projects. They both have characters animated on demand:

- [Fox](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Fox/Introduction/Intro.html)
- [Badger](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/Badger/Introduction/Intro.html)

The steps are:

1. Load a scn (or dae) file that contain the character and an animation (or just an animation and the skeleton of the character).
2. Trigger the animation with `addAnimation:forKey:` on the character's
   root node.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be able to use the `paused` property to achieve what you want.

Both `SCNScene` and `SCNNode` have this property. You should be able to pause the `SCNNode` and then unpause when you want the animation to run.

```
characterTopLevelNode.paused = true
// Or
GuyScene.paused = true

// Then to unpause just assign to false instead
```

Comment: Awesome info thanks! but the problem is that I don't know who to get the guy to animate